# How can I explain what is wrong with the sentence "She is having difficulty to shop"?

Tags: grammar

It should be, I believe "She is having difficulty shopping." But I am not sure how I can explain to someone who is a non-native English speaker why the form "She is having difficulty to shop" is not correct but "She is having difficulty shopping" is okay.

Comment: This belongs on English Language Learner's SE.   You may find that site more useful. // Also +1 tchrist

Comment: What is wrong is that the predicate _have difficulty_ can take an [Equi gerund complement](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/cliffs-equi-raising.pdf), but not an Equi infinitive complement.

Comment: after an adjective, verbs will (very) often take the gerund (ing) form. E.g It's not easy studying a new language.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it belongs on [ell.se]